# how to control a provider that contains information coming from firebasefirestore with more than one argument

Tags: flutter, firebase, model-view-controller, riverpod

I'm new to flutter, however I'm creating an app where the main objective is for the user to be able to filter the recipes. that is, in this application there will be many recipes and each recipe has a "time" "price" "tastes" "calories" "type". Given these values I do a firestore search and give the results.

In this application I am organizing the structure as follows "Repository" "Controller" and "Screen".
In the repository (place where I put the firebase calls) I put the following function:

```
Stream<List<Receita>> getReceitasRefeicao(
      String tipo, int maxPreco, int minLikes, int maxCalorias) {
    return _receitas
        .where('tipo', isEqualTo: tipo)
        .where('preco', isLessThan: maxPreco)
        .where('likes', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: minLikes)
        .where('calorias', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: maxCalorias)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (event) => event.docs
              .map((e) => Receita.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
              .toList(),
        );
  }
```

In the controller I'm used to using a reference to the repository function and using a STREAMPROVIDER to listen to the changes made, for example:

```
Stream<List<Receita>> getReceitasRefeicao(
      String tipo, int maxPreco, int minLikes, int maxCalorias) {
            return _receitaRepository.getReceitasRefeicao(tipo,maxPreco,minLikes,maxCalorias);
      }


final getReceitasRefeicaoProvider = StreamProvider.family((ref, String tipo, int maxPreco, int minLikes, int maxCalorias) {
  final postController = ref.watch(receitaControllerProvider.notifier);
  return postController.getReceitasRefeicao(tipo, maxPreco, minLikes, maxCalorias);
});


final receitaControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<ReceitaController, bool>((ref) {
  final receitaRepository = ref.watch(receitaRepositoryProvider);
  final storageRepository = ref.watch(storageRepositoryProvider);
  return ReceitaController(
      receitaRepository: receitaRepository,
      ref: ref,
      storageRepository: storageRepository);
});
```

However, until now in my application I only needed to pass an argument to these StreamProviders to fulfill my calls to firebase. In this case I have to pass more than one argument and I got an error:

**The argument type 'Stream<List> Function(StreamProviderRef, String, int, int, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream Function(StreamProviderRef, dynamic)'.**

I don't know what kind of StreamProvider to use now I've already searched but I didn't find anything.

I already have a StreamProvider that gives me all the recipes, so I'm thinking of using that StreamProvider and use some If statements but I don't think it's good practice.

Comment: I think you forgot to copy the code

Comment: Yeah @EdwynZN, Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah family only allows you to pass one argument, there are 3 ways to solve it now:

1. Check [Riverpod generator](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_generator)

This can help you create auto disposable or different providers with family attribute and more than one parameter

[image]

I'm just not sure if stream provider works with riverpod generator as of today (it's still an early package). You can try it like this:

```
@Riverpod(dependencies: [receitaControllerProvider]) /// Your other providers will need to be generated too so you pass the function here
StreamProvider<List<Receita>> getReceitasRefeicao(getReceitasRefeicaoRef ref, {
  required String tipo,
  required int maxPreco,
  required int minLikes,
  required int maxCalorias,
}){
  final postController = ref.watch(receitaControllerProvider.notifier);
  return postController.getReceitasRefeicao(tipo, maxPreco, minLikes, maxCalorias);
}
```

2. You can now pass a Record (If you're using flutter 3.10)

Just create a typedef (or not, it will still work but you'll have to declare all the Record as a type in your provider and its really long)

```
typedef ReceitasParams = ({String tipo, int maxPreco, int minLikes, int maxCalorias});
    
final getReceitasRefeicaoProvider = StreamProvider.family<List<Receita>, ReceitasParams>((ref, myReceitasParams) {
  final postController = ref.watch(receitaControllerProvider.notifier);
  return postController.getReceitasRefeicao(myReceitasParams.tipo, myReceitasParams.maxPreco, myReceitasParams.minLikes, myReceitasParams.maxCalorias);
});
```

3. The ol' reliable immutable class

Works with every Flutter version and no package required

```
/// Use Equatable, Freezed or override manually the hash and equal methods
class ReceitasParams {
  final String tipo;
  final int maxPreco;
  final int minLikes;
  final int maxCalorias;

  const ReceitasParams({
    required this.tipo,
    required this.maxPreco,
    required this.minLikes,
    required this.maxCalorias,
  });

}
final getReceitasRefeicaoProvider = StreamProvider.family<List<Receita>, ReceitasParams>((ref, ReceitasParams params) {
  final postController = ref.watch(receitaControllerProvider.notifier);
  return postController.getReceitasRefeicao(params.tipo, params.maxPreco, params.minLikes, params.maxCalorias);
});
```

Comment: I used the "3. The ol' reliable immutable class" and it worked. Thank you very much!
  I also noticed that if you pass a <List<'''''''''''>> as a parameter, the StreamProvider family doesn't work perfectly. As a solution could use "The ol' reliable immutable class" just to safe the List inside the class?

Comment: Yeah you can wrap it with a class too